# not recognizing script name as cmdlet, function etc

Tags: xaml, powershell

My project is to write a script with an XAML form that will display in PowerShell.

I have two script files. `FirstScript.ps1` which has the following code:

```psh
# Required to load the XAML form and create the Powershell Variables
.\LoadDialog.ps1 -XamlPath '.\ADMgmtForm.xaml'

Write-Output "Hello, World!"
Write-Output ""
```

My second script file `LoadDialogue.ps1` has the following code:

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
  [string]$XamlPath
)

[xml]$Global:xmlWPF = Get-Content -Path $XamlPath

# Add WPF and Windows Forms assemblies

try{
  Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase,
    system.windows.forms
} catch {
  Throw "Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework assemblies."
}

# Create the XAML reader using a new XML node reader

$Global:xamGUI = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((new-object 
System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xmlWPF))

# Create hooks to each named object in the XAML

$xmlWPF.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{
  Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $xamGUI.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Global
}
```

My Form file has the following code:

```xml
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid Margin="0,0,61,0">
    <Label Name="Label1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="68,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197"/>
    <Button Name="DispGrps" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="49,251,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Height="41" 
      FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Button Name="SelectGrps" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
      Margin="301,251,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" Height="41" 
      FontWeight="Bold"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I call `FirstScript.ps1` in PowerShell I see the output of "Hello World", but I also get this error message:

```
PS C:\Users\myusernamehere\Desktop\ADMgmtProject\Scripts> .\FirstScript.ps1
.\LoadDialog.ps1 : The term '.\LoadDialog.ps1' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At C:\Users\myusernamehere\Desktop\ADMgmtProject\Scripts\FirstScript.ps1:2 
char:1
+ .\LoadDialog.ps1 -XamlPath '.\ADMgmtForm.xaml'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo      : ObjectNotFound: (.\LoadDialog.ps1:String) [],
  CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
Hello, World!
```

I have tried initializing `. .\FirstScript.ps1` and I get the same error message. I have tried adding `&""` before `LoadDialogue` in my `LoadDialogue.ps1` script.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Double check that `FirstScript.ps1` and `LoadDialog.ps1` are actually in the same directory and that this directory is the current working directory when calling `.\LoadDialog.ps1` (`$pwd.Path`). Also, is you second file named `LoadDialog.ps1` or `LoadDialogue.ps1`?

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, thank you for your response. I am about to go into a meeting and will update you when I get done.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, my path name was incorrect. A very simple fix and it's now working. Thank you!